# Define a remove function

Tags: list, function, haskell

I'm having trouble with this exercise, please help !

Define a function remove that takes an integer and 
a list of integers as input and returns the list obtained by deleting
the first occurrence of the integer in the list;

```
delete :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be easier for us to assist if we know where you are stuck.

Comment: [Data.List.delete](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:delete)

Answer (score 6):

I'm learning Haskell, so my answer is not authoritative. Rather than posting the code that I've written to answer you question, I try to write the way I looked at the problem.

I approached it looking at the various cases (I've found that this helps with Haskell):

1. deleting whatever from an empty list ... that's easy
2. deleting something (`x`) from a non-empty list (`ys`):

   2.1. is `x` equal to the first element of `ys`? then I'm done ...

   2.2. otherwise I just have to delete `x` from the list starting after the first element of `ys`

Comment: 1. delete n [] = error"empty list"
2. delete n y 
         | n == y = []
         |otherwise = y
3. delete n (y:ys) 
         | n==y= ys 
         |

Comment: 1. delete _ [] = [] 2. delete x (y:ys) | x == y =ys | otherwise = y:(delete x ys)

Answer (score 5):

Think about delete as building a new list without the element in question, rather than removing the element itself. (sounds like homework so I'll be no more specific than that :))

Comment: uhm, the tough bit is it is the 1st element in the list and it might occur many times.

Comment: No problems.  Just think of the cases as MarcoS describes below.  If the head of the list is the element you want to delete, just use delete on the tail of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to give away the answer, but here it is, straight from [the source of Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#delete)

```
delete :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
delete = deleteBy (==)

deleteBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> [a]
deleteBy _  _ []     = []
deleteBy eq x (y:ys) = if x `eq` y then ys else y : deleteBy eq x ys
```

Normally I'd describe it here, but if you understand basic recursion, if statements, pattern matching, and the `:` operator, and partial application/currying, then it should be self-explanatory. Feel free to ask if any one of these is foreign to you.

Answer (score -2):

first: declare the function (look up how function declarations work) - depending on language it looks similar to this:

```
array
delete( int input1, array input2 )
{
}
```

then work on the body of the function

declare tha variables you need,
perform the array manipulation
return the resulting array.

Comment: question is on Haskell: functions are special and very different from _usual_ languages!